# Comparing strings with logical operators in an IF statement

Tags: string, comparison

I am trying to figure out how to compare strings within an if statement. Most of my code can be ignored, but is there for context. I am trying to add a message to my simple rock, paper, scissors game for when someone enters a string besides rock, paper, or scissors. Can someone tell me what I am doign wrong in the portion with asterisks around it?

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
     computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
     computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
     }
**else if (choice1 !== "rock" || "paper" || "scissors") {
    return "Your only options are rock, paper, or scissors you friggin plebian!";
}**
else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "Rock wins!";
    }
    else {
        return "Paper wins!";
    }
}
else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "Paper wins!";
    }
    else {
        return "Scissors wins!";
    }
}
else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "paper") {
        return "Scissors wins!";
    }
    else {
        return "Rock wins!";
    }
}
```

};

```
compare (userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// ...
else if (choice1 !== "rock" || choice1 !== "paper" || choice1 !== "scissors") {
    return "Your only options are rock, paper, or scissors you friggin plebian!";
}    
// ...
```

Boolean expressions don't read as we might say it in english, i.e. "Choice is not rock or paper or scissors".  Evaluating "choice" as a boolean is a perfectly syntactically valid thing to do in some languages, so take care in remembering to stupidly repeat the parameter. Otherwise these are the types of mistakes that take a while to find.  ;)

Comment: It took me a few readings to realize you were NOT calling me stupid, but rather the syntax. I need some sleep so i can keep learning rather than mashing my head against problems I have created for myself.
Thanks to everyone who pointed out what was a silly mistake, but just another step in learning.

Comment: @RanmaSaotome Ha!  I know that feeling well.  It happens to the best of us.  Sometimes it helps to do something completely different for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
else if (choice1 !== "rock" || choice1 !== "paper" || choice1 !== "scissors")
```

Your statement doesn't compile as "choice1 not equal to rock, paper, or scissors."

The compiler reads it as:

choice1 not equal to rock

OR

paper

OR

scissors

Each section after a logical operator must evaluate to a boolean, so it is only matching the string if it isn't rock, the second two won't match anything.

Answer (score 1):

`else if (choice1 !== "rock" || "paper" || "scissors")` should be:

`else if (choice1 !== "rock" || choice1 !== "paper" || choice1 !== "scissors")`